# Как запустить, завершить программу с помощью exec на php?

Tags: php, qt, qt5

Такая задача необходимо запустить консольное приложение на Qt с помощью php, чтобы эта программа отработала и завершилась, по возможности передав в код пхп результат, но может и не передавать, главное чтобы завершилась, чтоб пхп не висло. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта функция запустит любую программу и сразу передаст управление PHP. То есть программа выполнится в бэкграунде. Работает и в UNIX и в Windows

```
<?php 
    function execInBackground($cmd) { 
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
        } else { 
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Направьте стандартный вывод (stdio) и stderr в null, тогда php не будет ждать завершения команды:

```
shell_exec( $your_command . "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" );
```